# Count Duplicate Entries Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Firebase JSON data:

```
{
  "DjSunGazer" : {
    "-Lm23d6MZV22-yB7TnPr" : {
      "song" : "Ginuwine - So Anxious"
    },
    "-Lm23x2RnlgUJVLW0RFv" : {
      "song" : "Ginuwine - So Anxious"
    }
  }
}
```

Inside DjSunGazer, instead of adding a totally new song, I want to detect the duplicate and assign it a count of 2. Here is the code I have for adding a new song to my Firebase Database

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String s = "";
        String mGroupId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            s = snapshot.child("song").getValue(String.class);

            Log.d("GET KEY", mGroupId);
        }

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(AddSongRequest.getAssociatedAcct).child(mGroupId).child("song").setValue(mSongList.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition() + 1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

How can I prevent it from adding a totally new instance, and instead create another child of the name "count" that will update the values accordingly? I have been struggling with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like its because of the way you use `mGroupId`, specifically `.child(mGroupId)`, because the ID of both songs is different it will never find a match?

Comment: ah, that would make sense. So instead, I should just make them all under the same unique ID?

Comment: That would be one way to achieve it. What about nesting the ID under the song name instead, rather than your current setup with the song name nested under the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it'll be a lot easier to guarantee uniqueness if you use the thing that needs to be unique as the key of the node. So if the song title needs to be unique, use *that* as the key. Then use child nodes (for example with push IDs) under there to get the count.

So if you identify a song by its title, and use push IDs to track the requests:

```
{
  "DjSunGazer" : {
    "Ginuwine - So Anxious": {
      "-Lm23d6MZV22-yB7TnPr" : true,
      "-Lm23x2RnlgUJVLW0RFv" : true
  }
}
```

To add a request for this song, you'd do:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
root.child("DjSunGazer/Ginuwine - So Anxious").push(true);
```

Comment: well, it is for song requests, and I would like the person who sees the song requests to see how many times one song has been requested (which will suggest that will be the song that should be played)

Comment: Exactly: so store the song under its title (if that is how you identify a song), and store the requests under that. I added an example of this to my answer.